# Ansible URI module using POST with raw body giving unhashable type error

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to use Ansible to make POST call to a URL and receive a token. This token will then be used for subsequent API calls. I was able to use the Ansible URI module to make a few GET API calls but I'm having an issue making a POST call.

The curl command which works looks like this:

```
curl -L -X POST 'https://myapiurl.com/api/1/auth/login' -H 'host: myapiurl.com' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{
    "username": "user",
    "password": "pass"
}'
```

My Ansible task:

```
- hosts: lab
  connection: local
  tasks:
- name: Get token
  uri:
    method: POST
    url:  "https://myapiurl.com/api/1/auth/login" 
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/json
      host: myapiurl.com
    body:
      name: user
      password: pass
    validate_certs: no
  register: login
```

Verbose Error Output:

```
TypeError: unhashable type
fatal: [host-name]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "content": "",
    "elapsed": 0,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "attributes": null,
            "backup": null,
            "body": {
                "name": "user",
                "password": "pass"
            },
            "body_format": "raw",
            "client_cert": null,
            "client_key": null,
            "content": null,
            "creates": null,
            "delimiter": null,
            "dest": null,
            "directory_mode": null,
            "follow": false,
            "follow_redirects": "safe",
            "force": false,
            "force_basic_auth": false,
            "group": null,
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "host": "myapiurl.com"
            },
            "http_agent": "ansible-httpget",
            "method": "POST",
            "mode": null,
            "owner": null,
            "regexp": null,
            "remote_src": null,
            "removes": null,
            "return_content": false,
            "selevel": null,
            "serole": null,
            "setype": null,
            "seuser": null,
            "src": null,
            "status_code": [
                200
            ],
            "timeout": 30,
            "unix_socket": null,
            "unsafe_writes": null,
            "url": "https://myapiurl.com/api/1/auth/login",
            "url_password": null,
            "url_username": null,
            "use_proxy": true,
            "validate_certs": false
        }
    },
    "msg": "Status code was -1 and not [200]: An unknown error occurred: unhashable type",
    "redirected": false,
    "status": -1,
    "url": "https://myapiurl.com/api/1/auth/login"
}
```

Not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the body is wrong? Try putting `username` inested of `user`:

```
body:
  username: user
  password: pass
```

Comment: yes, username was part of it. i had to use username and not just name.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I needed to add "body_format: json" to the task like this:

```
- hosts: lab
  connection: local
  tasks:
- name: Get token
  uri:
    method: POST
    url:  "https://myapiurl.com/api/1/auth/login" 
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/json
      host: myapiurl.com
    body:
      username: user
      password: pass
    body_format: json
    validate_certs: no
  register: login
```